# Keep hidden columns hidden when pasting

Tags: vba, excel

I found and edited a macro that copies the range of cells from multiple workbooks into one workbook, Summary Sheet.

I would like hidden columns to remain hidden when pasted into DestRange.

For instance, if columns B, G, AO, GO are hidden in the source file, I would like to hide them in the destination file too. My macro copies and pastes but unhides all columns.

I tried to use `xlCellTypeVisible` but it doesn't copy hidden columns.

I also tried to put these lines into my code:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 256
SourceRange.Sheets("Copy Transposed").Columns(i).Hidden =
DestRange.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(i).Hidden
Next i
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub MergeSelectedWorkbooks()
Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim SelectedFiles() As Variant
Dim NRow As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim NFile As Long
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range
Dim i As Long

Set SummarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

FolderPath = "c:\Users\abcdefg\Desktop\input\"

ChDrive FolderPath
ChDir FolderPath

SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
NRow = 1

For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
    FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)
    Set WorkBk = WorkBooks.Open(FileName)

    Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets("Copy Transposed").Range("A2:DP2")
    Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow)
    Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
       SourceRange.Columns.Count)

    SourceRange.Copy
    DestRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    For i = 1 To 256
    SourceRange.Sheets("Copy Transposed").Columns(i).Hidden = DestRange.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(i).Hidden
    Next i
    NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False
Next NFile
SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Moreover I would like to copy only visible worksheet from the source file.

I put "Copy Transposed" because my current worksheet is named like that but the name will be always different.

I put `WorkBk.Worksheets("1")` instead of `WorkBk.Worksheets("Copy Transposed")` but it copied only 1st column.

Comment: Do all your source sheets have the same hidden columns? If not, a column that you hide after copying from one sheet will be unhidden when you copy from the next sheet and so on...

Comment: yes all worksheets have the same hidden columns that's why I'd like to keep the same "template" in Dest Range too

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the answer to my questions. I added `.PasteSpecial Paste:=8` and it worked. I also changed the name of the worksheet to number and it also worked.

Here is my code:

```
Sub macro_final()
Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim SelectedFiles() As Variant
Dim NRow As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim NFile As Long
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range

Set SummarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

FolderPath = "c:\Users\abcdefg\Desktop\input\"
ChDrive FolderPath
ChDir FolderPath

SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
NRow = 1

For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
    FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)
    Set WorkBk = WorkBooks.Open(FileName)

    Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:DZ2")
    Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow)

    SourceRange.Copy
    With DestRange
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    NRow = NRow + DestRange.rows.Count
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

Next NFile
SummarySheet.rows.AutoFit
End Sub
```